# Can I add a SharePoint Picture Library as a source of Office Clipart?

Tags: picture-library, office

We've got a pile of stock photography that we own in a 2010 picture library but nobody uses it.  It would be great if they could access that resource from inside Word or whatever via the Clipart organiser.  Does anybody know much about the clipart organiser in Office 2010, and if I can add a SharePoint location, can I push that out via a group policy?

Comment: Is there another stack exchange I should ask this in?